# From Python script how to run other Python script?

Tags: python, windows, bash, shell, ubuntu

In my main Python script, I want to call another python script to run, as follows:

`python2 ~/script_location/my_side_script.py \ --input-dir folder1/in_folder \ --output-dir folder1/out_folder/ \ --image-ext jpg \`

From inside my Python script, how exactly can I do this?

I will be using both Windows and Ubuntu, but primarily the latter. Ideally would like to be able to do on both.

Comment: Use the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). If you run into difficulty, post another question showing the code you tried.

Comment: Would appreciate a quick answer with the syntax to get this going, thanks

Comment: Run `sys.executable` if it should be locked into the current version or virtual environment. Otherwise if it should use some other version or installation of Python, add a shebang to the script and, in Unix, make it executable via `chmod +x my_side_script.py`. Then you can run it directly. In Windows you'll either have to explicitly run the script using py.exe (if 3.x is installed) or python.exe, or use `shell=True` to have CMD run it using the .py file association. The py.exe launcher supports Windows paths in shebangs as well as virtual Unix paths (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/python`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could import the script in your main file.

Suppose you have two files: myscript.py and main.py

```
# myscript.py
print('this is my script!')
```

```
# main.py
print('this is my main file')
import myscript
print('end')
```

The output if you run `main.py` would be:

```
this is my main file
this is my script
end
```

**EDIT:** If you literally just want to call `python2 my_side_script.py --options asdf`, you could use the `subprocess` python module:

```
import subprocess

stdout = subprocess.check_output(['python2', 'my_side_script.py', '--options', 'asdf'])

print(stdout)      # will print any output from your sidescript
```

Comment: I'm looking to literally call "python2 my_side_script.py --options asdf" from within my main.py python script. How can this be done?

Comment: Note that the OP needs Windows support as well, which has no `python2` command. I don't know if all Unix (Linux, BSD, macOS, etc) systems even have `python2`. Anyway, to use the current Python interpreter in Windows, run "python.exe" (it's in the application directory, which is always checked first). More generally, use an executable script with a shebang, and on Windows run it with `shell=True` (and hope, a lot of hope).

Comment: @eryksun sounds good. I can do a quick if check to see if windows or not.

Comment: right, @eryksun. This solution assumes that OP's path is setup to include his desired python interpreter and should work on both windows and ubuntu. making his script an executable is also an option if OP doesn't want to add `python2` to the path.

Comment: @khuynh, subprocess uses `CreateProcess` in Windows. When searching for an executable the application directory is *always* checked first, so python.exe (or just `python`, since CreateProcess will add ".EXE" for us) for the current interpreter can always be found in Windows, even if `PATH` is empty. In Unix it depends on `PATH`, but Unix dumps most commands in one or two directories, so it's not an issue.

Comment: thanks @eryksun, I didn't know that. I'll update my answer to include this info when I get a chance to test with windows.